# how to install a python file with ament_cmake

Tags: python, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an ament_cmake package that is mostly c++ but it also contains a python script in the "package_dir/script" folder (following the ROS1 directory convention). My expectation is that the script could be invoked using "ros2 run" and also could be referenced from launch files as an executable node.

Would it be possible to install this python file as an executable script from this ament_cmake package?
If that is possible, what would be the cmake "install" function I should use for the python file or the scripts directory?

Should I instead create another separated ament_python package for that single script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363630/how-to-install-a-python-file-with-ament_cmake/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2020-10-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the solution I found for that issue:

```
install(PROGRAMS
        scripts/myscript.py
        DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2020-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2